# ReactTable - Error: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component

Tags: json, reactjs, react-native, datatable, react-redux

I am trying to import data into a ReactTable. Currently, I am just using test data to set the table up and ensure it is displaying how I want it to.

I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component.
```

Here is the code for the table columns:

```
const columns = [{  
      Header: 'ID',  
      accessor: 'id',
     }
     ,{  
      Header: 'Name',  
      accessor: 'name' ,
      },

etc...
```

Code for table:

```
<ReactTable  
  data={this.state.data}  
  columns={columns}  
/>
```

The data is printing correctly in the console, but when I implement the `<ReactTable>` I get the error above.

Comment: Will need more details to help.

All I can think of is you have some `random text` that you `mistakenly added in the return function`.

Comment: Hi, appreciate the comment, if I remove the ```<ReactTable>``` then the error is not thrown, so my guess is that there is something wrong with the data or table.